# How to type emojii android keyboard with different unicode?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji, custom-keyboard, emoticons

I have been using [this library](http://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) to implement emoji on Android SoftKeyboard. The library works fine, but when I use emoji in TextMessage, they appear like android style and not like they are in the library (Whatsapp style). This is the screenshot:

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: If you ask a question, it should be a question and not a f... tag cloud.

Comment: See, how I fixed your question. Now it is nearly understable.